# Angular 8: Two way data binding with radio button not working. The variable value is always undefined

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I am facing issues with two way data binding for radio button control. I am trying to bind a string variable declared in component with the html template. The value recorded in this variable is always undefined. When I replace value with [value] then the web page itself doesn't get rendered.
The component has the variable declared as loginMode: string;
I am using alert(this.loginMode) to inspect the value of the variable

Below is the HTML template...

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row" >
        <div class="p-2">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input class="radio-checkbox" name="login" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="loginMode" 
                          value="Password Login" >Password Login
                 </label>
         </div>
         <div class="p-2">
             <label class="checkbox-inline" >
                <input class="radio-checkbox" name="login" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="loginMode" 
                            value="OTP Login" >OTP Login
                </label>
          </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try printing the property value using the interpolation in the template `{{ loginMode }}` to see if its really binding or not. Because you may be calling `alert` before it gets binded.

Comment: I used the {{loginMode}} There is no value printed.

Comment: @akotech I created a dummy project <https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkbc6f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html> Here the radio button works fine. Any idea what other settings is causing the issue in production environment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported `FormsModule` inside `app.module.ts`

Comment: Yes, FormsModule is imported

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my new patch of html code was inserted in between existing < form > < /form > tag. When I placed the new code out of this < form > tag, the two way data binding worked fine. Not sure what the reason is. Would be great if anyone could explain the reason.